# Authorize USB drive

Tags: c#, windows, usb, usb-drive

Is there any method or suggestion how to prepare and authorize an USB drive in program written in C#? I do not want to prepare some kind of a whitelist but somehow detect that USB drive was prepared by me. The USB drive would be used to update my program.

Detecting hidden files and folders is not a solution because user can always display/delete all those hidden things.

In addition the program has got to detect that USB drive is authorized on Windows >= XP.

***EDIT***

The USB drive should work on every OS just like regular USB except the thing that It should be authorize-able in my program.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can do it in C#, by pinvoking the low level drivers, but you could think about the fundamental structure of the disk FAT, MBR, etc.  For example you might be able to use the [Host Proctected Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area).

Comment: Or you could try to partition the drive, putting a sector of 'signature' data in one of the partitions and marking it as not having a strandard disk structure (e.g. something other than FAT32, etc).  Again, this isn't something I'd say was easy to do from c#.

Comment: To anyone who downvoted my question: please tell me why did u do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some [Mike of SST advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241321/authorize-usb-drive/24242930?noredirect=1#comment37441418_24241321) I've managed to prepare a solution which satisfies me. It does not use C# directly but it is manageable in that language,

Steps to do in my solution:

1. Create the smallest possible unallocated partition in your USB drive (in my case it's 7.8MB)
2. Based on USB drive infos create a hashed string and write it to that unallocated partition.

In that solution user simply doesn't know if that USB is authorized, he can format a visible partition and write everything on it. Even copying the image of that drive doesn't give an authorization to copied usb drive.

Using [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) I am able to read and write that hash and I can run that process directly from c#.

Comment: Where do you put the update files? Because so far it sounds to me like you managed to create an unforgeable packet but left the lid open, so anyone can put sth in or take sth out and your program will just buy it.

Comment: To be honest, the folder where I put my update files does not really matter. The problem was with authorization - not the location of files. Even if user will put some invalid update files I'll know it by identifying the USB drive by it's hashed unique number on unallocated partition. Detecting broken files is just another issue.

Comment: As far authorizing an USB drive goes, however, I have to admit you've found a nice solution, at least it seems so.

Comment: Thank you that you approved my solution and thank you for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try to avoid a special file? You place a hidden txt file with generated hash key in it. This hash is generated base on your USB drive manufacturer serial number and secret key (which your program has). When you place a USB drive in computer, your program read hash key from the file and compare it with calculated by the program. If they are same, you authorize USB drive. You just doesn't authorize USB drives without this file. If you want to user not able to remove this file, you should use hidden partition, but it's more complex solution.

Comment: The problem in that solution is that user can delete this file by an accident and lose a possibility to be have an authorized USB

Answer (score 0):

What about encrypting the entire drive or putting an encrypted file/container on it? The password could be embedded in your program. (This is not the most secure solution, but an easy one for your purposes.)

Comment: Adding "special" files/folders would not work because it can be easy removed. I'm thinking about a solution where user would not know that this USB is authorized or just make them wonder why it is.